# How do you get the current directory in compact framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How do you get the current directory where your app is running?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Utilities
{
    static public class DirectoryHelper
    {
        static public string GetCurrentDirectory ()
        {
            return Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetName ().CodeBase);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Answer (score -1):

Public Shared Sub WriteDBStatus(ByVal strString As String)

```
    Try

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\DBStatus"

        Dim sr As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
        If Not IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
            sr = IO.File.CreateText(FILE_NAME)
            sr.WriteLine(strString)
        End If
        sr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```